# Transferring files from PC to App local storage Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing an app which would need to have files pushed to its local store for its consumption.
Is it possible to transfer files from a PC to a windows phone app local folder or say one of the Special-use folders in the local folder such as Shared/Media from a desktop application in a wired or wireless manner ? Are there any size restrictions as to the maximum data a local folder could contain for transfers done this way ?

On further research on WP8 storage i got to know about isolated storage explorer and i envision the desktop client to be similar to isolated storage explorer but customized and simplified only for the app is that possible ? meanwhile let me search more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it does seem like it is possible. You can use the Isolated Storage Explorer in WP8.

Look at the **Replacing files in the local folder** in the following article on how to move files between your computer and your phone:

[How to use the Isolated Storage Explorer tool for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_CopyingFilesfromIsolatedStorage)

Comment: AFAIK You can’t view isolated storage for apps that you’ve installed from the Windows Phone Store, what i want is something similar for an app installed from the store and a very app specific storage explorer client would be ok, meaning the app should be enabled to talk to the desktop client

Comment: OK i understand now. I don't think that is possible outside of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i ended up using [socket programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202874%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to solve this, Stephen Cleary's blog post [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) helped a lot to brush up the basics